# Can't convert false to String

Tags: ruby

I have URLs:

```
/foo
/bar/test
```

If there's only one `/` in the URL, I am trying to prepend `item[1]` to it. Otherwise, I want to match the first `/something` from the request path with `gsub`. Something is going wrong here:

```
((request.path.count "/" == 1) ? "/#{item[1]}/#{request.path}" : request.path.gsub( /^\/[^\/]+/, "/#{item[1]}" ))
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: `app/views/shared/_header.html.haml:24:in 'count'` is the first line

Comment: value of request.path ?

Comment: @shiva How can I output that in a HAML file? ie. and prevent it from just rendering the "Error" view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I have reproduced the error :

```
"aaa".count(false) # Can't convert false to String
```

It means you need to write

```
request.path.count "/" == 1)
```

as

```
(request.path.count("/") == 1)
```

If you write `request.path.count "/" == 1)`, then that line has been parsed as `(request.path.count("/" == 1))`. Thus equality test has been performed first, i.e `"/" == 1`. `"/" == 1` returns `false`. Then the `false` being passed as an argument to `request.path.count(false)`. It then throws the error as **Can't convert false to String**.

Comment: As an aside, is it usually wise to be doing this sort of logic in the HAML files?

Comment: @benhowdle89 In Ruby if you write, `meth 1`, it is actually `meth(1)`. Same way, if you write `meth 1==2`, Ruby will assume you are passing `1==2` as an argument to `meth`, i.e `meth(1==2)`. Now the expression `1==2` will be evaluated first and then the result will be passed as an argument, like `meth(false)`.